# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) with socket streams

Tags: ios, sockets, ssl, nsstream

I have a TLS certificate for my domain which works with https in a browser. I'm trying to understand how these certs work exactly, but it's not making sense. Could someone point me in the right direction on how to set up TLS with socket streams? From Apple's docs it sounded like all you need to do is `[stream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];` and if the server certificate is valid, then everything is good. I think I'm missing something.

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)[url host], port, &readStream, &writeStream);

_inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
_outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[_inputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
[_outputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

[_inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[_outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[_inputStream setDelegate:self];
[_outputStream setDelegate:self];

[_inputStream open];
[_outputStream open];
```